# Blank line after enabling Gzip in WP-Supercache

Tags: wordpress, gzip

I am having an issue here with Wordpress and WP-Supercache.

When I enable gzip compression in the plugin, a white line appears at the top of my pages, breaking some features as my RSS feed, because it can't have a white line before the `<?xml` line.

It only happens when I enable gzip. It disappears when I disable it.

What can it be?

Answer (score 0):

Check your .htaccess file and/or php.ini to see if gzipping is already enabled. If it is, that's probably the reason for the white space and junk characters. If you don't know, ask your web host.

Comment: Hi! I checked everything and gzip is not enabled, also, Google Adsense is telling me to enable it, so I don't think it is being enabled twice.